# Question on analysis principle of continuity on P95 of Courant's Intro to Calculus and Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, real-numbers

In Courant's Intro to Calculus and Analysis I Page 95, it say:

The completeness of the real number continuum is expressed by the basic continuity principle (on page 8): Every nested sequence of intervals with real end points contains a real number. To prove this cnosider closed interval $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$, each interval contained in the preceding one, whose lengths $y_{n} - x_{n}$ form a null-sequence (as limit n -> $\infty (y_{n} - x_{n}) = 0 $). We claim there is a real **$x$** contained in all $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$: the sequences $x_{n}$ and $y_{n}$ will then have **$x$** as a limit. To prove this we replace the nested sequence $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$ by a nested sequence of rational intervals $[a_{n}, b_{n}]$, containing the $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$. This rational sequence will then define the desireed real number **$x$**. For each **$n$**, let $a_{n}$ be the largest rational number of the form $p/2^n$ less than $x_{n}$ and $b_n$ the smallest rational number of the form $q/2^n$ greater than $y_n$, where **$p$** and **$q$** are integers. Clearly, the intervals $[a_{n}, b_{n}]$ form a nested sequence representing a real number **$x$**. If **$x$** lay outside one of the intervals $[x_{m}, y_{m}]$, say **$x < x_m$**, there would exist a rational $r$ with $x < r < x_m$, whence for all sufficiently large $n$ we would have:

$y_n \le b_n < r < x_m \le x_n$

which is impossible. Hence all intervals $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$ contain the point $x$

I have issues understand first, when usng interval $[x_{m}, y_{m}]$, where should this interval be as compared with $[x_{n}, y_{n}]$

Second, how did the author get the left part of the inequality, namely: $y_n \le b_n < r$? I know how he got $r < x_m \le x_n$, but the left part is so hard to see without a x-axis graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well, first they should be nested in some manner. Something along the lines of

$$ n < m \Rightarrow [x_m, y_n] \subset [x_n, y_m]. $$

Secondly, the $b_n$'s are by definition (or construction) upper bounds of the $y_n$'s. If there's a rational number in $(x, x_m)$ then if you go out far enough in the sequence there's an integer $n$ such that $$y_n \leq b_n < r < x_m \leq x_n.$$ This more or less follows by the definition of $$ b_n := \inf \{ \frac{q}{2^n} > y_n, q \in \mathbb{Z} \}, $$ 
as since you can find a integers $q$ and $n$ such that $$q < r 2^n.$$

Dividing both sides by $2^n$ and taking the infimum yields $b_n < r$.

Comment: Hi Moon Bears-C, are you saying n < m -> $[x_m, y_m]$ is subset of $[x_n, y_n]$? Also I still have no idea as "if you go out far enough in the sequence" as to where should it go...

Comment: Yes, that's generally what nested means for sets - you either have the "largest" russian doll and diwndle down to "smaller" russian dolls OR you start with the "smallest" russian doll and add layers from there. "Going out far enough" is a colloquial term for how a sequence is behaving at "the tail". It means that there exists an integer $n$ such that the sequence $a_n$ satisfies some property. In this case it satisfies an inequality.